# Fitting list item in a nav using percentage

Tags: css

As you can see from below, I'm having trouble fitting Tab 5 along with my other list items. I set the width of each to be 20%, but it doesn't work. But when I set it to 19% it works fine. What is causing Tab 5 to move to the next line?

```css
.progress-region {
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid;
}

.progress-nav {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px
}
.progress-nav .step-labels {
    margin: 0 0 20px
}

.progress-nav .step-labels.items-5 .item {
    width: 20%
}

.progress-nav .step-labels .item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #aaa;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear
}

.progress-nav .progress-bar {
    height: 3px;
    background: #f5f5f5

}

.progress-nav .progress-bar .inner-bar {
    background: #3381d0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="progress-region">
    <div class="progress-nav">
        <div class="back-arrow" style="display: none;"></div>
        <ul class="step-labels items-5">
            <li class="item" data-index="0">Tab 1</li>
            <li class="item active" data-index="1">Tab 2</li>
            <li class="item" data-index="2">Tab 3</li>
            <li class="item" data-index="3">Tab 4</li>
            <li class="item" data-index="4">Tab 5</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="inner-bar" style="width: 50%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative you could use the flex box model. I've not included all the required prefixes for it to work on older browsers simply to condense the answer. You can find information about that [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
.progress-region {
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.progress-nav {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px
}
.progress-nav .step-labels {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.progress-nav .step-labels.items-5 .item {
  flex: 1;
}
.progress-nav .step-labels .item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -o-transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear
}
.progress-nav .progress-bar {
  height: 3px;
  background: #f5f5f5
}
.progress-nav .progress-bar .inner-bar {
  background: #3381d0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="progress-region">
  <div class="progress-nav">
    <div class="back-arrow" style="display: none;"></div>
    <ul class="step-labels items-5">
      <li class="item" data-index="0">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="item active" data-index="1">Tab 2</li>
      <li class="item" data-index="2">Tab 3</li>
      <li class="item" data-index="3">Tab 4</li>
      <li class="item" data-index="4">Tab 5</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="inner-bar" style="width: 50%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is `display: inline-block` on the list items. By default inline-block elements generate space between them*. When you reduce the `20%` width to `19%`, the margin/gap difference is equaled.

*[**Space between inline-block elements**](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

```css
.progress-region {
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid;
}

.progress-nav {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px
}
.progress-nav .step-labels {
    margin: 0 0 20px
}

.progress-nav .step-labels.items-5 .item {
    width: 19%
}

.progress-nav .step-labels .item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #aaa;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear
}

.progress-nav .progress-bar {
    height: 3px;
    background: #f5f5f5

}

.progress-nav .progress-bar .inner-bar {
    background: #3381d0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="progress-region">
    <div class="progress-nav">
        <div class="back-arrow" style="display: none;"></div>
        <ul class="step-labels items-5">
            <li class="item" data-index="0">Tab 1</li>
            <li class="item active" data-index="1">Tab 2</li>
            <li class="item" data-index="2">Tab 3</li>
            <li class="item" data-index="3">Tab 4</li>
            <li class="item" data-index="4">Tab 5</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <div class="inner-bar" style="width: 50%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a gap between the inline blocks (https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).